# ColdFusion Tag Handler Error

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a a cf page that creates a pdf which has been working for a while and after a server reboot this weekend it is now throwing the following error:  (This is CF8)

```
The tag handler document does not have a setter for the 
attribute scaleToFit specified in the Tag Library Descriptor.

The error occurred in  line 149

147 :       </cfquery>
148 : 
149 :       <!--- Build PDF Document --->
150 :       <cfdocument format="pdf" name="Invoice" 
                    orientation="landscape" margintop="2" marginbottom=".8"
151 :       marginleft=".5" marginright=".5" fontembed="no" localurl="true">
```

Comment: Did the server do some sort of update during the reboot? The error basically means the `scaleToFit` attribute doesn't exist. So if you're using that anywhere, it's causing the error. So if it were removed, the page should load. This is a guess though.

Comment: It sounds to me like a hotfix you applied didn't take. Reapply it.

Comment: There is no scale to fit attribute on the page so that confused me even more.

Comment: To my knowledge no hotfixes were applied just windows updates

Answer (score 0):

Adam,
You were correct I have discovered the problem was a half applied hotfix on one of the clustered servers